# I need to read data from file into a vector of struct

Tags: c++

i hope you guys can help as the title says i need to read data from a file into vector of struct, but i need to use the readfile function to read different structs at different times. Its the for loop that puzzles me

```
for(temp; getline(infile, temp.whatever) && getline(infile, temp.whatever2); i++)
    structname.pushback(temp);
```

this ties the function to an individual struct. Its a bit counter productive to write another function to read in a different struct. Obviously this works but is there a way to make this more reusable. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `temp`? it doesn't seem to have a type... Where is `i` declared?

Comment: Sorry temp is the temp name for the struct and i is declared before the loop int i = 0;

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: To me your question is a bit unclear. Are you asking about two different struct types? Like `struct A { ....};` and `struct B { ....};`

Comment: "i need to use the readfile function". Assignment? What is 'readfile'?

Comment: Thats exactly what im asking but each struct hold different data i can read it in as a string and convert later thats not the issue.

Comment: Sorry im on my phone at the moment will post a full example later

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do something to make the code usable for different struct types.

However, all struct types **must** have the fields used inside the function.

It could look something like this:

```
template<typename T>
void readData(vector<T>& v, istream& infile)
{
    T temp;
    while(getline(infile, temp.whatever) && getline(infile, temp.whatever2))
    {
        v.push_back(temp);
    }
}

int main() {
    // Add code for infileA and infileB

    vector<myStructA> va;
    readData(va, infileA);  // or readData<myStructA>(va, infileA); if you prefer

    vector<myStructB> vb;
    readData(vb, infileB);  // or readData<myStructB>(vb, infileB); if you prefer

    ....
    ....

    return 0;
}
```

So here both `myStructA` and `myStructB` must have the member `whatever` and `whatever2`. This could be implemented by using a common base class for `myStructA` and `myStructB`.